# CSS transition happens only once on button click

Tags: html, css, animation

#### What I am trying to make:

I am trying to make a button controlled animation where a small stick figure moves to the right or the left depending on which button is clicked.

#### Problem:

Animation happens only once

Applies only to right and down buttons

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
    #stage{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        border-style: dashed;
        border-color: gray;
        border-width: medium;
    }

    #actor{
        width: 13px;
        height: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-image: url("E:/Website Projects/man.PNG");

        -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-out 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 2s ease-out 0s;
        transition: all 2s ease-out 0s;
    }


</style>

<body>
    <div id="stage">
        <div id="actor"></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button class="control" id="top">TOP</button> <br>
        <button class="control" id="left">LEFT</button> <button class="control" id="right">RIGHT</button> <br>
        <button class="control" id="down">DOWN</button>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var maxWidth = 100;
    var maxHeight = 100;

    var top = document.querySelector("#top");
    var left = document.querySelector("#left");
    var right = document.querySelector("#right");
    var down = document.querySelector("#down");

    top.addEventListener("click",moveTop,false);
    left.addEventListener("click",moveLeft,false);
    right.addEventListener("click",moveRight,false);
    down.addEventListener("click",moveDown,false);

    function moveTop(){
        var actor = document.querySelector("#actor");
        actor.style.top -= "25px";
    }

    function moveDown(){
        var actor = document.querySelector("#actor");
        actor.style.top += "25px";
    }

    function moveRight(){
        var actor = document.querySelector("#actor");
        actor.style.left += "25px";
    }

    function moveLeft(){
        var actor = document.querySelector("#actor");
        actor.style.left -= "25px";
    }

</script>

</html>
```

#### Screenshot

[image: stick man]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add `25px` to `25px` as a string.

You can use the `+=` and `-=` for integers only.

You would want your function to look like this:

```
function moveDown(){
    var actor = document.querySelector("#actor");
    var num = parseInt(actor.style.top) || 0;
    actor.style.top = num + 25 + "px";
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5CMWW/

Comment: so why does it happen the first time ?

Comment: Because the first value is nothing. So you're adding the string "" to "25px" making it "25px".  When you add it to it again, you're adding "25px" to "25px" making your result "25px25px".

Comment: This is close. Just use `parseInt` for the `add` variable, add/ subtract 25 and then set the position. :)

Comment: @Titanium what is `|| 0` used for  ?